# Proof of a simple theorem without prime factorisation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I‘m supposed to prove the following without using prime factorisation:

Let a<sub>1</sub> $\neq$ 0, a<sub>2</sub>, … , a<sub>n</sub> $\in \mathbb{Z}$ be pairwise co-primes. Show that a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> * … * a<sub>n</sub> are also coprimes.

It’s so simple, but how can we do that without prime fact.? In class we just had Bezouts Lemma, the Chinese remainder theorem and Fermats little theorem resp. Eulers theorem.

Comment: Well, if you have Bezout then presumably you have the fact that if a prime $p$ divides a product $mn$ then $p$ divides at least one of $m,n$.

Comment: Use Bezout theorem to translate the assumption and to prove that $a_1$ and $a_2a_3$ are coprime.